# Aggregate in MongodbCharts

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-charts

I'm having an error when I'm putting my aggregation in mongodbChart. This code is working fine in normal aggregation but when I'm putting it in MongodbCharts it gives me an error.

FunctionError: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$group'

code

```
{
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$displayName",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$ne": null
      },
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no `$addFields` in your code.

Comment: Try `$set` which is an alias for `$addFields`